# Difference between comments and comments with equals sign in application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Why do lines inside `application.js` appear to be commented out?

I see tutorials with directives to add lines of code to the `application.js` file, yet the lines added seem to be commented out.

A basic example [here](https://medium.com/@biancapower/how-to-add-bootstrap-4-to-a-rails-5-app-650118459a1e)

Here's what it my file looks like (the lines I've added appear to be comments):

[image]

I'm suspicious that the `=` may be negating the comment, but in every language I've known, once a comment is declared, that line is considered a comment no matter what else is on it

Comment: `=` wouldn't be negating the comment. However, there might be some standard tool that parses comments and looks for that to do something. You can see this with [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) (e.g., `@return a user name` will document what a function returns) or [userscript metadata](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[sprockets](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/sprockets) is using this kind of comment `//= require xx`
for End User Asset Generation as they call it.

This is not related to the language but more of something that this tool does.

It is called annotation

The reason this pattern is quite popular is that it doesn't affect the actual code in any way.

At the end of the day, this is only to collect all files compress them and serve them to the user and not actually changing anything related to code.

Comment: it might be a silly question, but why does sprockets use this convention? (as opposed to uncommented lines of code)

Answer (score 2):

From [sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#directives):

> Directives are special comments in your asset file and the main way of
>   interacting with processors. What kind of interactions? You can use
>   these directives to tell Sprockets to load other files, or specify
>   dependencies on other assets.
>
> For example, let's say you have custom JavaScript that you've
>   written. You put this javascript in a file called `beta.js`. The
>   javascript makes heavy use of jQuery, so you need to load that before
>   your code executes. You could add a `require` directive to the top of
>   `beta.js`:
>
> ```
> //= require jquery
>
> $().ready({
>   // my custom code here
> })
> ```
>
> The directive processor understands comment blocks in three formats:
>
> ```
> /* Multi-line comment blocks (CSS, SCSS, JavaScript)
>  *= require foo
>  */
> ```
>
> ```
> // Single-line comment blocks (SCSS, JavaScript)
> //= require foo
> ```
>
> ```
> # Single-line comment blocks (CoffeeScript)
> #= require foo
> ```
>
> > Note: Directives are only processed if they come before any application code. Once you have a line that does not include a comment
> >     or whitespace then Sprockets will stop looking for directives. If you
> >     use a directive outside of the "header" of the document it will not do
> >     anything, and won't raise any errors.
>
> Here is a list of the available directives:
>
> - [`require`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#require) - Add the contents of a file to current
> - [`require_self`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#require_self) - Change order of where current contents are concatenated to current
> - [`require_directory`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#require_directory) - Add contents of each file in a folder to current
> - [`require_tree`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#require_tree) - Add contents of all files in all directories in a path to current
> - [`link`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#link) - Make target file compile and be publically available without adding contents to current
> - [`link_directory`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#link_directory) - Make target directory compile and be publically available without adding contents to current
> - [`link_tree`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#link_tree) - Make target tree compile and be publically available without adding contents to current
> - [`depend_on`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#depend_on) - Recompile current file if target has changed
> - [`stub`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets#stub) - Ignore target file

Answer (score 1):

Not always, for example in PHP you have annotation comments: https://php-annotations.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UsingAnnotations.html

In JS, when using flow, you are adding comment on top of the file, like this:

```
// @flow

[file content]
```

It's actually common pattern